# SWIG+%nspace: is it possible to rename/strip a base namespace?

Tags: java, c++, namespaces, rename, swig

I am working on a binding from C++ targeting java (and later Python).

My classes are like this (ex: `mymodule.h`)

```
namespace BaseNS {
    class A {};
    class B {};

    namespace NestedNS {
        class C {};
        class D {};
    };
};
```

when using the namespace feature (`%nspace` or `%feature("nspace")`) like so:

```
%module MyModule
%{
    #include "mymodule.h";
    using BaseNS;
%}

%feature("nspace");
%include "mymodule.h";
```

I get the following java binding:

```
|- MyModule.java
|- MyModuleJNI.java
`- BaseNS
 |- A.java
 |- B.java
 `- NestedNS
   |- C.java
   |- D.java
```

1. Is there a way to instruct SWIG to rename `BaseNS` to `RenamedNS`?

I tried to meddle with the `%rename` instruction using:

```
%rename (RenamedNS) BaseNS; // does not pick namespace
%rename (RenamedNS) ::BaseNS; // still does not work
```

2. As an alternative, is there a way to stip `BaseNS` away, to produce a binding like so:

   ```
   |- MyModule.java
   |- MyModuleJNI.java
   |- A.java
   |- B.java
   `- NestedNS
    |- C.java
    |- D.java
   ```

(still keeping `NestedNS` but removing BaseNS from the path).

thanks.

Comment: It looks like the answer is going to be "no" for this one. %nspace and %rename just don't give you the control you want.